# Problem making a clickable polygon to open a box in a webmap

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I'm new to JavaScript and Leaflet. I tried to add a polygon on a map & make a text box appear when the polygon is clicked.

I think my code is fine, and a cursor appears when you scroll over the area of the polygon, but no text box appears when clicked.

I would love for someone to look over my code and see if they can spot where I went wrong:

[Github link](https://github.com/JaymesMc/displayingBoxinMap)

I tried making a clickable polygon to display a box. The mouse cursor signifies that the polygon is there & should be clickable. But the box is never displayed.

```js
// Create a polygon layer (My code has actual coordinates)
var polygon = L.polygon([
      [ ** Coordinates ** ]).addTo(map); polygon.setZIndex(600);

    // Function to handle the click event on the polygon
    function handlePolygonClick(event) {
      // Display the "box"
      var boxElement = document.getElementById("box");
      boxElement.classList.remove("hidden");
    }

    // Bind the click event to the polygon
    polygon.on("click", handlePolygonClick);

    // Add a marker
    var marker = L.marker([ ** Coordinates ** ]).addTo(map);

    // Check if the marker is within the polygon
    var isWithin = polygon.getBounds().contains(marker.getLatLng());

    if (isWithin) {
      console.log("Marker is within the polygon.");
    } else {
      console.log("Marker is outside the polygon.");
    }
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 76%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#box {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 0px;
  left: 1180px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 800;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="box" class="hidden">
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your question accordingly and provide debugging details in the question itself in the form of a [repro]. Links to external resources are not an acceptable nor suitable replacement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a popup to your polygon. In your function to handle the click, the parameter passed is the `LeafletEvent` where `event.target` is the polygon object clicked.

Use `event.target.bindPopup('text')` and open the popup with `openPopup`.

```
 // Function to handle the click event on the polygon
 function handlePolygonClick(event) {
       event.target
      .bindPopup(`<p><b>Textbox</b><br>Hi, I'm the textbox</p>`)
      .openPopup();
 }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/textbox-polygon-is-clicked?file=index.js

Comment: You're a legend! Thank you so much!